# Allow using wildcard in the Discussions tag filter

Tags: feature-request, status-review, tags, discussions-space

Other places that filter questions allow wildcards. For example `[ecmascript*]` will expand to `[ecmascript-6] or [ecmascript-5] or [ecmascript-2016] or [ecmascript-next] or [ecmascript-2017] or [ecmascript-harmony] or [ecmascript-2020] or [ecmascript-intl] or [ecmascript-3] or [ecmascript-2018] or [ecmascript-temporal] or [ecmascript-2021] or [ecmascript-4] or [ecmascript-2019] or [ecmascript-2022] or [ecmascript-2024]`

Places where the wildcard behaviour triggers:

- [In search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript*):
  [image: Search for "[ecmascript*]" expands to all tags that start with this text.]
- [As a custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript*?sort=Newest&edited=true):
  [image: Custom filter for "ecmascript*" expands to all tags that start with this text.]
- In Watched tag:
  [image: Using "ecmascript*" as a Watched tag highlights a question with the tag "ecmascript-6".]
- In ignored tags:
  [image: Using "ecmascript*" as an Ignored tag hides a question with the tag "ecmascript-6".]

The wildcards are very useful for technologies that get new releases (ECMAScript is on a yearly release cadence) or might have multiple "sub-tags" that use the main technology as prefix (consider [java-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream), [java-native-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-native-interface), [java-threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-threads), [java-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time), etc), and other situations where it is hard to enumerate all tags that exist or could exist for a technology. Yet all of them are of interest. Furthermore, new tags names can grow but after defining one wildcard, all new tags created are still Watched, Ignored, exist in custom filters, etc.

The Discussions tag filter does not accept the wildcard syntax. If I go to [the overview page](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions), open the tag filter, type in `ecmascript*`, and finally click "Apply Filters", the only thing that happens is that the page refreshes but the filters remain at zero.

Allow wildcards in Discussions filters, so it is easy to follow all relevant discussions.